# setting variable Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am new to linux shell scripting and I am trying to set the following variable to get the size of a folder path passed in from keyboard. I keep getting an error saying invalid option. T

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? The error disappears when I remove the "size" variable and leave it as is.

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo -e "\nEnter the first directory (relative path)"
read dir1

size=find $dir1 -type f | wc -l 

 echo $size
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
size=$(find $dir1 -type f | wc -l)
```

Using the `$()` notation means that a command should be run and its output placed on the line.

This is because variables are assigned literal text values.

```
myvar=foo
```

will put the string "foo" into `myvar` and not the value of the variable foo or the result of the foo command.

```
myvar=$foo
```

will put the value of the variable `foo` into `myvar`.  And

```
myvar=$(foo)
```

will put the result of running the command `foo` into myvar.

There is a special part of the shell syntax that lets you assign variable values before running a command, and those variable values are only set for that one command.  It looks like this:

```
x=foo1 y=foo2 command parameter ...
```

The way you have written your line

```
size=find $dir1 -type f | wc -l
```

`size` is assigned a value of "find", then

```
$dir1 -type f  # this won't be a valid command
```

is executed as a separate command.

Comment: @Teddy13: I've added some explanation.